# What kind of cable looks like HDMI but has only one slanted edge?

Tags: hdmi, cable, displayport, connector

What kind of cable/connector is this? It looks like an HDMI connector, with very similar pins, but it has a slanted edge on only one side and the other side is square.

[image]

Comment: HDMI has two slanted corners, not just one.

Comment: @slhck  Why was this question closed as "too localized"? There must be millions of these ports and cables out there, and I found this question by searching for "HDMI one side square" -- this was the top Google result and it answered my question immediately.

Comment: @Johnny The rationale behind closing questions like "Here's an image — what's this?" is that they're not easily searchable and therefore will not help people in the future. In that case, with a little more context and description, it's probably worth keeping it. Thanks for your comment; I reopened the question.

Comment: FWIW, I found this searching for "connector looks like HDMI".  So this one is definitely pretty easily searchable.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is a [DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) — it's pretty common on desktops and quite a few laptops.

[image]

Comment: Worth noting that you can use this kind of port to connect to HDMI cables if you just get a DisplayPort-to-HDMI adapter. They have the same basic job.